# What java permissions are needed to load log4j2 with security manager?

Tags: java, security, policy, securitymanager

I have the following policy file:

```
grant codeBase "file:./Cookie.jar",
Principal javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal 
    "MyUsr@domain.com" 
Principal javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal 
    "OtherUsr@domain.com" {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.*", "read,write";
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.home", "read";
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.home", "read";
permission java.io.FilePermission "foo.txt", "read";
};


grant {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*","read,write";
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.Cookie";
    permission java.security."*";

};
```

Whenever I execute: `java -jar Cookie.jar` my program works as intended and I have no problem loading log4j.

However, when I execute the following to enable the security manager (using the above policy file):

`java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==java.policy -jar Cookie.jar -Djava.security.auth.login.config=auth.conf`

I end up getting this ERROR:

> StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add lo
>   g4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

This is the same error I would get if I didn't have log4j on the classpath, however, log4j is on the classpath.

I have determined for certain that the issue is caused by the security manager. I can only assume that I need to add a certain permission to my policy file in order for the Log4j2 library to load properly, but I can't figure out what permission I need to add.

Could someone please tell me what I'm missing here, and explain why this is happening? Thanks!

EDIT: Dang, I fixed this somehow, but don't remember exactly how. I'll update here if I remember.